# Set my external ip Address by SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, routing, ip, ssh-tunnel

I have Vserver with 2 external ip Addresses

```
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.2/32 scope host venet0
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.204/32 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.204 scope global venet0:0
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.205/32 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.205 scope global venet0:1
```

When i ssh into the Server on the .205 Address i get the .204 Address as external ip Address

```
curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl |cut -d " " -f 5
xxx.xxx.xxx.204
```

How can i make sure the connected ip address is used as external ip address?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without at least 2 physical interfaces and setting multi WAN. Right now you are using aliases and from my experience the first interface with route(s) to the target will be used.